# Rust linkedlist push_sort function

Tags: rust, linked-list

I'm trying to implement my own Linkedlist in Rust (for learning purposes).

The structures I use :

```rust
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        return Node {
            value: val,
            next: None,
        };
    }

    pub fn new_with_next(val: T, next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>) -> Self {
        return Node {
            value: val,
            next: next,
        };
    }
}

struct List<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

I've implemented a function to push an item to the right place in a sorted list (we're assuming it is). It works fine (after long hours of struggle) but as a rust beginner and because rust looks very different from other languages I use, I wonder if there isn't a more idiomatic way to implement this in Rust.

```rust
    fn push_sort(&mut self, val: T) where T: std::cmp::PartialOrd {
        match &mut self.head {
            Some(head) => {
                if head.value >= val {
                    self.head = Some(Box::new(Node::new_with_next(val, self.head.take())));
                    return;
                }
            },
            None => {
                self.head = Some(Box::new(Node::new(val)));
                return;
            }
        };

        let mut current = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(node) = current {
            if node.next.is_none() {
                node.next = Some(Box::new(Node::new(val)));
                return;
            }

            if val < node.next.as_ref().unwrap().value {
                node.next = Some(Box::new(Node::new_with_next(val, node.next.take())));
                return;
            }

            current = &mut node.next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'If let Some(head)' is more idiomatic

Comment: In place of what ? I was not fan of using too munch `is_none()` or `unwrap()` but I was not able to replace with with `if Some` and match without causing issues

Comment: Obligatory linked list question: have you read the [too many lists book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)?

Comment: Yes I did (part1 to 4) but I chose to leave out the lifetime for now, and it didn't help me for this specific function

Comment: "More idiomatic" is off-topic for Stack Overflow, you may want to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `match` and `while let` that can all be done in a single loop, same for checking nodes for being `Some` or `None` in the loops body and its condition:

```rust
    fn push_sort(&mut self, val: T)
    where
        T: std::cmp::PartialOrd,
    {
        let mut current = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(c) = current {
            if c.value >= val {
                let old = std::mem::replace(c, Box::new(Node::new(val)));
                c.next = Some(old);
                return;
            }
            current = &mut c.next;
        }
        *current = Some(Box::new(Node::new(val)));
    }
```

Comment: OK thx, this work very good. I assume `std::mem::replace` is an equivalent to Options `.took()` ?
Just a question, how does `*` works, I had many using this on thing that didn't implement `Copy` or `Clone` ?

Comment: `*` just derefernces the rest of the expression, on the left hand side of an assignment that means assigning to the target of a reference instead of the variable itself. So in this code it changes the last `Node`s `.next` (because that's where the `while` loop drops out) instead of changing `current`.

Comment: `std::mem::replace` replaces and returns what's behind it's first argument with what you pass as it's second argument. `Option::take` is essentially `std::mem::replace(&mut opt, None)`.

Comment: Ok, If I understand `current` is a mutable varibale that store a mutable reference, `*` is used to update the variable "pointed" by current instead of changing current value i.e the "pointer"?